# jsonarray to multy textView

Tags: java, php, android, layout

i created a code for get jsonarray like this from a php file

```
{name:alex,family:alexx},{name:john,family:Doe}and ...
```

i i convert them to string With code below in HOMe_activity:

```
public class home extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userPref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    String useridnow = pref.getString("userid", null);
    if(useridnow == null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(home.this,MainActivity.class);
       home.this.startActivity(i);
    }
    new Getfeed(home.this,useridnow).execute();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
class Getfeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private String userid;
private Context context;
RelativeLayout rellay;

public Getfeed(Context context, String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://fb.facenegah.com/android/showfeed.php");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feedid","0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uper", "0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("downer", "0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isprofile", "0"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        return responseText;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
   //Toast.makeText(context, "Json: "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("salam");

        for(int i=0;i<movies.length();i++){
            JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
            String characters = movie.getString("user_esm");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Json: "+characters , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
            View rowView2 = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowlay);
            View homeview =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);
            View homeview2 =  (LinearLayout) homeview.findViewById(R.id.homelay);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView.setText(characters);
            //setListAdapter(rowView);
            //this line give me an error for addView with no suggestion in adroid studio
            rowView2.addView(rowView2);




        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

}
```

and i have custom layout with just two textview:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="124dp"
android:text="New Text"
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_weight="0.24" />
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="124dp"
android:text="New Text"
android:id="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_weight="0.24" />
```

i just dont know tell my code to while that jsonarray exist
its put values in textView in this custom layout
and show them on HOme activity repeatly when user open it
just like Tango newsfeed

Comment: please help me with this  its not hard question

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about adding your custom layout (now populated from the JSON file) to your main layout, you can do something like this:

Give the layout you're adding your custom layouts an id.  For example, I've given mine `main`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/main"
...
```

Get a reference to the main layout in your code like this:

`RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);`

Then, after creating each custom layout, as you are doing in your for loop, add your `rowView` to `main`:

`main.addView(rowView);`

I don't know what the Tango newfeed looks like, but if you're creating something like a newfeed you probably want to use some kind of adapter instead of manually adding (and then removing?) layouts. For example, you could put a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in your xml and then use a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) to populate the data.  Using a list adapter means that android will do things like take care of scrolling and automatically reuse views as they scroll of the screen to improve performance.

Comment: thank you for your answer sir... but i get error when try addView ... i put my hole code in my question see it

Comment: and if its better i use listView please give me an example wtih my codes ,, i try it simple but i want imageview and multi textview and edittext for my loop